# Can't start MySQL, port 3306 busy

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

I'm trying to start MySQL from XAMPP (under Windows Vista), but it's saying that's port 3306 is busy.

What would be the best way with check what application is using that port and how to free it?

Comment: Surely you must mean WAMP? XAMPP is for linuX.

Comment: no, I'm using XAMPP, runs fine on Vista. Do you think I should switch to WAMP?

Comment: my bad, I thought the first letter of the `*ampp*` series defined to OS, but apparently I was wrong :).

Comment: lol, removed xampp, installed wamp... seems working now!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a command shell, run:

```
netstat -b -p TCP
```

and look for a line that says `localhost:3306` in the second column. Below this is the application's name using the port.

Comment: outputs a long list, but non of it has localhost or 3306 in it... :/

Comment: It's possible that instead of `localhost` it prints your machine's name. However, a line with `:3306` should appear somewhere.

Comment: netstat: invalid option -- 'b'  What did you mean there?

Comment: This question is related to Windows which _also_ has `netstat` (and accepts the `-b` option for displaying the *b*inary bound to an address). Someone edited my answer and put some \*nix related stuff into it which might have lead you to assume that this isn't actually Windows related.

Answer (score 21):

Just Open task manager and Kill MySql service.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and was stuck on this thing for a day and I couldn't find a perfect answer anywhere.
So I gave it a shot on my own and it worked. This solution is for Windows users. I use Windows 7.

My xampp control panel was displaying an error that port 3306 is busy and in use by some file (name was specified).. say "filename.de".

Now follow the following steps:

1. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and open Task Manager.
2. Open the "Processes" list and Check for "show all processes" under the list of processes. If you don't see any such option, don't worry! as sometimes administrator permission is required to show some processes.
3. Now, when you click on "show all processes" button, all the process will be displayed.
4. Now, switch to "services" tab in the task manager, and a list of services will be displayed. Now look for a service named "filename.de" <-- filename that was diplayed in the error message in xampp.
5. When you find that service, 'right-click', and then click in option.. GoTo Process.
6. You will be redirected to the "Processes" tab with focus on a process corresponding to that service. 'Right-Click' and then click on "end process tree".
7. Now, the issue has been solved! But might have to do the same thing again when you restart your PC. So it is best to keep your PC in sleep-mode.
8. Otherwise, to solve this issue permanently, open "msconfig" and uncheck that particular process from the services list and click on apply. and you can restart your system.

Answer (score 5):

I've been having trouble for hours on this error. I was trying to run MySQL from XAMPP after quite some time. It gave errors, similar to yours, it said that port 3306 is in use. If you:

- are running on Windows 10
- are avoiding to change the port number of MySQL from 3306
- can't see any program using the 3306 port from `netstat`
- reinstalling and deleting everything yet it still give the same error
- are enabling and using Hyper-V
- all of the other solutions didn't work

This is the solution that worked for me:

- Go to the most right of the taskbar and right-click the connection icon, click `Open Network & Internet settings`
- Click `Change adapter options`
- Right-click and Disable everything that relates to Hyper-V

I ran MySQL again at now it works.

Comment: this solved my issue! I had about 10 hyper-v connections and after disabling it worked.

Comment: This solution helped me aswell. For me there was a VMware Network Adapter that was causing the problem. Disabling it, solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

As Mentioned By @Segun Emmanuel Run the Following Command:

```
netstat -a -b
```

You will get a list of Applications that are using different PORTS. Press `Ctrl + F` and write 3306 to find out which Application is using PORT 3306.

[image]

After this, Go to Task Manager via Search Bar or by pressing `CTRL + ALT + DEL`. Then Under the Background Processes, find out `mysqld.exe`, right-click on it and you will find an option to close it, namely "`End Task`".

[image]

Then go to your **Xampp Control Panel** and start the MySQL service.

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm! thanks a lot. I was trying to install the MySQL DB via the MySQL installer & encountered this issue on windows 10. I had to open the CMD in admin mode & execute the given command, found the culprit who was still dwelling on 3306 & killed him as you suggested. The MySQL MSI installer was blocked due to the 3306 port already in use issue. It got resolved as soon as I killed the mysqld.exe process from the 'Services' tab list. Yas! +1 Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If mysql is not starting in xampp, it might be a port conflict issue. Mysql run by default on port 3306. you need to check if another application is occupying that port. use following command to check app occupying a port

```
Linux: netstat -tulpn | grep 3306
Window: netstat -a -b 
Mac: lsof -nP -i4TCP:3306
```

if you find an application occupying that port, stop the application and restart xampp. As an alternative, you can go to php.ini file or click configure in the xampp for mysql and change the mysql port to 3307

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was javaw.exe which was starting on port 3306. This exe does not cause problem if I am logged in using single user in my Windows 10. But if I have multiple logins, it starts this exe for each user and blocks MySQL to start on 3306 port.

Going to task manager and killing this exe for the other user fixed the issue and MySQl could start.

Answer (score 2):

Windows icon -> Open **cmd.exe**.
Type `netstat -a -b`.
Find what's using it. In my case it was this:
[image: Image 1]

So, I went to **task manager**. There were no process called so. The I went to **services** and disabled these two:

[image: Image 2]

Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This command kills the existing mysql process and perhaps one can start it afresh

```sh
sudo pkill mysql
```

It has helped me solve this challenge most of times

```
1. Turn off the application which is using this port, open terminal and run "lsof -n -P -i | grep 3306" to figure out.
2. Use different ports, right click on the server -> Edit.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem (slight variation as I was using MAMP)

I found this problem was due to having MySQL Workbench installed, MySQL Workbench started the mySQL service on bootup which in turn stopped MAMP being able to use the port.

To fix this I had 2 options,

1. Uninstall MySQL Workbench
2. Open Task, click services tab, kill the current MySQL service

This then allowed MAMP to use port 3306

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if you have installed mysql two times. mysql by default uses the port 3306. If you have installed it twice then already there is a mysql at your port number 3306. So you will have to change your port.

If you are using xampp then you can easily change your port. Steps to change port:
Step 1: Open your xampp as administrator.
Step 2: Click on 'Config' at the top right corner of your xampp.
Step 3: Click on 'Service and Port Settings' and after that change the main port of mysql from 3306 to 3307 and the click on save.
Step 4: Then click on 'config' which is in front of mysql and open 'my.ini' file which will be a text file.
Step 5: Now wherever in the text file you see the port number mentioned as 3306 change it to 3307 and then save the file.

After doing this again start your mysql server and it will start running on port 3307.

This worked for me and I hope it will work for anyone else who encounters the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, a simpler way on Windows is:-

1. Go to Task Manager
2. Go to Services
3. There will be a services named MySQl80 right click on it and then select
   "Stop"
4. Try and start the MySQl module on XAMPP server again

Answer (score 0):

If  you where not able to find any application or process listening on port `3306`, you might need to check **your network adapters**.

- Disable adapters you do not use.
- Pay also attention to the **Hyper-V** generated network adapter, disable it if you don't need it. Sometimes it can reserve some ports and commands like `netstat` will not be able to find it out

Answer (score 0):

1. Run XAMPP with Administrator
2. If you already installed MySQL Service, Uninstall it and install again. If you not already install it install MySQL Service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is available only on the latest version of XAMPP but
just copy everything in the backup folder in XAMPP->MYSQL->BACKUP
and paste (replace everything) in your data folder in XAMPP->MYSQL->DATA

This did the trick for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34804856)