# Xampp mysql error when connecting

Tags: mysql, server, xampp

i have this problem:
   I try to start the mySql from xampp but i get

```
   14:45:16  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
   14:45:16  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing 
                        dependencies, 
   14:45:16  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by 
                        another method.
   14:45:16  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
   14:45:16  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
   14:45:16  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
   14:45:16  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

I've been looking for an answer for like 4 hours and i can't find it. Can someone tell me how to fix this? I already tried to go to /xampp/mysql/data and delete ibdata. And also tried to change the port from 80 to 8080

Comment: MySQL runs on `3306` port by default. Check who is using that port. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/6136471/2845389

Comment: if i try this, i get this error: The requested operation requires elevation.

Comment: FIXED It was another mysql process that was using the 3306 port. Once i stoped it and ran mysql again, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that 80 and 8080 are not used and also set the process to run as sudo.