# mySQL is not starting at all

Tags: mariadb

These are the errors (attached below). I have tried all the solution previously suggested on overflow and none is working.
-When i delete ibdata1, it doesn't seem to go away.I find data of 75,776kb every-time i reopen data file.

```
11:57:38 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:57:38 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:57:38 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:57:38 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:57:38 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:57:38 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
11:57:38 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size to 10 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size is now 10 MB.
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5242880 bytes
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5242880 bytes
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=11452
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 7
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-01-24 11:44:50 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Did you check the possible issues one by one?

Comment: _Little Note_ Its mariaDB not MySQL

Comment: [How to check port 3306](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136389/cant-start-mysql-port-3306-busy)

Answer (score 0):

The "tablespace" called `ibdata1` is *vital* to operations of MySQL and MariaDB.  Do not remove it; you will lose any database tables you have created.

It comes back because it must have it and it is initialized if it is missing.  The size always starts out the same due to a configuration parameter.  It may grow later.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` seems to be initialized at 16MB.  It is dubious as to whether it will work at that tiny size.  Certainly performance will suffer.  Suggest at least 128M.  See `/etc/my.cnf`, or perhaps somewhere else.