# MySQL is not Starting in Apache

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache

```
16:00:21  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
16:03:47  [mysql]   Problem detected!
16:03:47  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" MySQL"!
16:03:47  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
16:03:47  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
16:03:47  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I have this above problem. Please help!

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/18177185/10464991

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xampp MySQL does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and try to make your question as clear and easy to answer. it seems that something else is listening on port 3306 - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136389/cant-start-mysql-port-3306-busy