# php 8.0 projects , Xampp apache and mysql unexpected closing

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

14:19:00  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

14:19:00  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application

14:19:00  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

14:19:00  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...

14:19:00  [mysql]   Status change detected: running

14:19:02  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped

14:19:49  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

**I delete database update files, xampp ran for 3 minutes and stopped, how is something like this possible?**

Comment: It has a timeout of 180 seconds somewhere? Who'd know? But the very first message indicates, that you already have a database running on the mysql standard port 3306

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't start MySQL, port 3306 busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136389/cant-start-mysql-port-3306-busy)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57107464/9992854  this solution , solved mysql problem, but now apache stops after it starts running.

21:18:28  [Apache]  Status change detected: running

21:18:28  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped

21:18:28  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

21:18:28  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,

21:18:28  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

21:18:28  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

21:18:28  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

21:18:28  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this

21:18:28  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

---

I figured it out.

1.open xampp and click to apache inline with config. choose Apache(httpd.conf)
find Listen 80 and change example :Listen:8086 find ServerName localhost:80 and change again 8086 save ,close.

2.click to same config but Apache(httpd-ssl.conf) and find port number probably its 443 instead of 4434 . find 
ServerName localhost:443 instead of 4434. SAVE AND CLOSE

3.Rightest CONFIG click
SERVICE AND PORT SETTING click
main port and ssl port ADD to their numbers.

4.an error message will appear on the screen. No problem, okay.

5.START Apache and Mysql AND done.